# VBA Date Format For Variable

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I need to turn content in a spreadsheet column from text to a date.

The cell format is **text** and the inputters were instructed to input a date as "ddmmyyyy".

Accidents happened and I found some content that would not parse as a date, including entries like "Unknown".

So I used a variable declared as a date and wrote an error handler to deal with content that would not parse.

Now for the bit I cannot work out.

If the date was 3rd March 2000 and someone input that as "03332000" that will not parse because "33" cannot be a month or a day; it is caught by the error handler as I wanted.

But if it was input as "03132000" I can't think of a way of preventing VBA converting that to a valid date as "13/03/2000".

Declaring a format for the date variable will not prevent VBA parsing the date.

I can write something that tests number range of the day and month part of the string but that is extra lines of code and I was hoping to do it just by the error handler.

Comment: Please show your existing code - much easier to tweak that than to have us try and guess exactly what you did.  You can try using DateSerial() and parsing out the specific parts of the entry using Left()/Mid()/Right()

Comment: Tim Thanks. I'll modify the post in a bit.

Comment: Tim, by the time I had rewritten the code (I am at home now) @Gary's Student had confirmed that I have to test the components of the date for validity.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you don't need to test for validity, just that you could prevent Excel from swapping the day and month if it felt like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place:

```
03332000
```

in cell **A1** and run:

```
Sub CheckDate()
    Dim s As String, d As Date
    s = Range("A1").Text
    d = DateSerial(CInt(Right(s, 4)), CInt(Mid(s, 3, 2)), CInt(Left(s, 2)))
    MsgBox s & vbCrLf & d
End Sub
```

You will get:

[image]

So even though a valid month can only be in the range [1-12], Excel is trying to "help" you by interpreting the 33 as a projection of future date.  For example, if the month was entered as 13, Excel will treat it as *December* of the following year!

You can't rely on error-handling for this. You need checks like:

```
Sub CheckDate2()
    Dim s As String, d As Date
    Dim dd As Integer, mm As Integer, yr As Integer

    s = Range("A1").Text

    yr = CInt(Right(s, 4))
    mm = CInt(Mid(s, 3, 2))
    dd = CInt(Left(s, 2))

    If yr = 0 Or yr < 1900 Then
        MsgBox "year is bad"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If dd = o Or dd > 31 Then
        MsgBox "day is bad"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If mm = 0 Or mm > 12 Then
        MsgBox "month is bad"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    d = DateSerial(yr, mm, dd)
    MsgBox s & vbCrLf & d
End Sub
```

You can also do other checks like looking at the length of the field, etc.

Comment: Gary's Student  Thanks, I just have to check the individual parts then. Thanks everyone for looking at this.

Comment: @River42  Any time you allow humans to enter data, you will have to perform some type of validation. *(I have nothing against humans; many of them are pretty accurate)*

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it a little differently and let Excel do the work.

```
Public Function ValidateDate(ByVal strDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim intDay As Integer, intMonth As Integer, intYear As Integer, dtDate As Date

    ValidateDate = True

    On Error GoTo IsInValid

    If Len(strDate) <> 8 Then GoTo IsInValid
    If Not IsNumeric(strDate) Then GoTo IsInValid

    intDay = Left(strDate, 2)
    intMonth = Mid(strDate, 3, 2)
    intYear = Right(strDate, 4)

    dtDate = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)

    If DatePart("d", dtDate) <> intDay Then GoTo IsInValid
    If DatePart("m", dtDate) <> intMonth Then GoTo IsInValid
    If DatePart("yyyy", dtDate) <> intYear Then GoTo IsInValid

    Exit Function

IsInValid:
    ValidateDate = False

End Function
```

... this will ensure that anything related to leap years etc. will still work correctly and it will ensure that all entries are validated correctly.

[image]

Comment: Uggh - `Goto`. You can avoid Goto if you set `ValidateDate` = False in the first place, and then set `ValidateDate = (DatePart(...) = intDay) And [...]` . You only get to this line if `Len(...) = 8 And IsNumeric(...)`. All in all, you could reduce this to about 6-8 lines.

Comment: @AJD Maybe I didn’t want to. It was very much on purpose. Having it split out like that makes it better to debug if wanting to determine exactly why an entry failed the test. It also splits it out for readability. It’s not always about reducing the amount of lines of code.

Comment: The main point of my comment is that `Goto` is a sign of code stink. You can achieve a better outcome without the `Goto` by rethinking your conditionals (especially if you start with a `defaultOutcome =TRUE` or a `defaultOutcome - FALSE`. And yes, you can still break out each conditional into a separate line for debugging purposes (e.g. `Test1 = Conditional` : Test2 = Conditional2 [...] finalTest = Test1 And test2 And [... etc]`) so it is not always about saving lines.

Comment: @AJD it’s your opinion. I can see the exact conditions I am wanting to check for and from a logical perspective, it highlights the points that I am wanting to jump out at. Thanks for the advice but I’m good thanks.

Comment: Not opinion - good coding practice. However, if you do not want to take this advice, then I am good also thanks.